# How does one add a callback for a gem's model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rails-engines

I have my own app. And I use some gem. This gem has, for example, User model.

How I can add my custom callback (after_save) for User model (which defined in gem without and callback for this model)?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this using an initializer, monkey-patching the `User` class in the gem:

```
# config/initializers/some_gem.rb
module SomeGem
  class User
    after_save :my_callback

    private
    def my_callback
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have error when I try to use your example (I changed SomeGem to MyNagios and User to Check) - `.../config/initializers/my_nagios.rb:3:in `<class:Check>': undefined method `after_update' for MyNagios::Check:Class (NoMethodError)`

I try to add collback for this class - [link](https://github.com/vintyara/my_nagios/blob/master/app/models/my_nagios/check.rb)

Comment: Yeah, I understand why, I forgot to add `Check < ActiveRecord::Base` :) Thanks!

Comment: Checked it again. With given solution I totally rewrite Check class and lose all existing methods, so Check class has only one method after that - my_callback :(

Comment: I see, this happens when your class from the initializer is loaded *before* the original class. Try requiring the original gem first as the first line in your initializer: `require mynagios` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by monkey-patching the User class in an initializer as already described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37373389/476712).

Alternatively, you can use the [rails-observers](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers) gem to keep your logic outside outside third party classes:

> Observer classes respond to life cycle callbacks to implement trigger-like behavior outside the original class. This is a great way to reduce the clutter that normally comes when the model class is burdened with functionality that doesn't pertain to the core responsibility of the class